# Python: How to change same numbers in a Series/Column to other values?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change the values of a very long column (about 1mio entries) in a data frame. I have something like

```
####ID_Orig
3452  
3452  
3452  
6543  
6543
...
```

I want something like

```
####ID_new
0  
0  
0  
1  
1  
...
```

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
j=0
for i in range(0,1199531): 
    if data.ID_orig[i]==data.ID_orig[i+1]:
        data.ID_orig[i] = j
    else:
        data.ID_orig[i] = j
        j=j+1
```

Which takes about ages... Is there a faster way to do this?
I don't know what values `ID_orig` has and how often a single value comes up.

Comment: Are you using the "Pandas" library? The question is not clear about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html), but if duplicated groups then output values are set to same number.

Another solution with comparing by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`) of [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) is more general - create always new values, also if repeating group values:

```
df['ID_new1'] = pd.factorize(df['ID_Orig'])[0]
df['ID_new2'] = df['ID_Orig'].ne(df['ID_Orig'].shift()).cumsum() - 1
print (df)
   ID_Orig  ID_new1  ID_new2
0     3452        0        0
1     3452        0        0
2     3452        0        0
3     6543        1        1
4     6543        1        1
5      100        2        2
6      100        2        2
7     6543        1        3 <-repeating group
8     6543        1        3 <-repeating group
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this …

```
import collections


l1 = [3452, 3452, 3452, 6543, 6543]
c = collections.Counter(l1)
l2 = list(c.items())
l3 = []

for i, t in enumerate(l2):
    for x in range(t[1]):
        l3.append(i)

for x in l3:
    print(x)
```

This is the output:

```
0
0
0
1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following. In the following implementation duplicate ids in the original id will get same ids. The implementation is based on dropping duplicates from the column and assigning a different number to each unique id to form the enw ids. These new ids are then merged into the original dataset

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import time

num_rows = 119953
input_data = np.random.randint(1199531, size=(num_rows,1))
data = pd.DataFrame(input_data)
data.columns = ["ID_orig"]

data2 = pd.DataFrame(input_data)
data2.columns = ["ID_orig"]

t0 = time()
j=0
for i in range(0,num_rows-1): 
    if data.ID_orig[i]==data.ID_orig[i+1]:
        data.ID_orig[i] = j
    else:
        data.ID_orig[i] = j
        j=j+1

t1 = time()
id_new = data2.loc[:,"ID_orig"].drop_duplicates().reset_index().drop("index", axis=1)
id_new.reset_index(inplace=True)
id_new.columns = ["id_new"] + id_new.columns[1:].values.tolist() 
data2 = data2.merge(id_new, on="ID_orig")

t2 = time()

print("Previous: ", round(t1-t0, 2), " seconds")
print("Current : ", round(t2-t1, 2), " seconds")
```

The output of the above program using only 119k rows is

```
Previous:  12.16 seconds
Current :  0.06 seconds
```

The runtime difference increases even more as the number of rows are increased.

**EDIT**
Using the same number of rows:

```
>>> print("Previous: ", round(t1-t0, 2))
Previous:  11.7
>>> print("Current : ", round(t2-t1, 2))
Current :  0.06
>>> print("jezrael's answer : ", round(t3-t2, 2))
jezrael's answer :  0.02
```